# Using PHP ternary operators to pass data to a method

Tags: php, methods, ternary

I've been working on some custom classes including a debug bug method. Using a constant debug variable

```
define('DEBUG', 3);
```

I set what level of debug I want to display. From FALSE (none), 1 (basic), 2 (medium), 3 (advanced), etc etc.

Throughout the code I have calls to said debug method. Exp:

```
if(DEBUG == TRUE)
    $this->status("DB connection",NULL);
```

Can this be condensed into a ternary operator? something like:

```
$this->debug($title, $response, $die) = (DEBUG == TRUE) ? ("DB Connection", NULL) : (NULL) ;
```

I know its a bit longer but having it all on one line etc would make it easier to maintain.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this would do. Would it not be wiser to check for the flag in `$this->debug()`?

Comment: @Pekka Damnit! I'm asleep at the wheel! I need coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it the other way around. Make a `debug` method/function, which you call with a debug level, always, without condition. Inside that method, decide whether the level is met.

```
$this->debug('DB connection', DEBUG_INFO);

public function debug($message, $level) {
    if (DEBUG >= $level) {
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though the debug method is a little more complicated than this example, it's exactly what I was looking for.
Instead of the IF/then though would a case select be a better option as I have multiple levels of debug?

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. :)

Comment: Awesome, not the answer I was aiming for but does the job with less code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

And why not put the test `if (DEBUG == whatever)` inside the `$this->debug` function?

Then your code looks like:

```
$this->debug("DB Connection", NULL);
```

And your debug function:

```
function debug($title, $response, $die = FALSE)
{
    if (DEBUG == whatever)
      dosomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are so inclined as to put it all in one line, you can just use

```
DEBUG && $this->status("DB connection",NULL);
```

However, this may affect the readability of your code compared to just using if-statements.